# Weird symbol in score for harp

Tags: notation, harp

In this score for harp, there's this weird symbol: (outlined in red)

[image]

I have no idea what it means, is it some kind of glissando?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The overlaid circle and plus generally mean [damping a string](http://sites.siba.fi/en/web/harpnotation/manual/damping-techniques/damp-single-strings).  Combining that with small noteheads and a range shows which strings to damp.  Harmonically this makes sense here, to prevent those low strings, plucked in the previous bar and a half, from polluting the C major chord that follows.

Here's another example of exactly that [symbol](https://www.harpspectrum.org/harpworks/composing_for_harp/images/sacred_harp_notation.gif), along with variations.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst it looks rather like a Coda sign, I think it means damp the strings. But exactly how, and when I couldn't find. It's not any kind of gliss.

Comment: Good guess - see Camille's references!